# Delete duplicate nodes between two nodes in Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

Due to unwanted scrip execution my database has some duplicate nodes and it looks like this

[image: Bad Graph]

From the image, there are multiple nodes with 'see' and 'execute' from p1 to m1.
I tried to eliminate them using this:

```
MATCH (ur:Role)-[c:CAN]->(e:Entitlement{action:'see'})-[o:ON]->(s:Role {id:'msci'}) 
WITH collect(e) AS rels WHERE size(rels) > 1 
FOREACH (n IN TAIL(rels) | DETACH DELETE n)
```

Resulting in this:

[image: Worse Graph]

As you can see here, it deletes all the nodes with 'see' action.
I think I am missing something in the query which I am not sure of.
The good graph should be like this:

[image: Good graph]

EDIT: Added one more scenario with extra relations
[image: Bad graph2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works if there is more than one extra :) and cleanses your entire graph.

```
// get all the patterns where you have > 1 entitlement of the same "action" (see or execute)
MATCH (n:Role)-->(e:Entitlement)-->(m:Role)
WITH n,m,e.action AS EntitlementAction,
     COLLECT(e) AS Entitlements    
WHERE size(Entitlements) > 1

// delete all entitlements, except the first one
FOREACH (e IN tail(Entitlements) |
     DETACH DELETE e
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query pretty explicitly is matching the "See" action.

```
MATCH (ur:Role)-[c:CAN]->(e:Entitlement{action:'see'})
```

You might try the query without specifying the action type.

Edit:

I went back and played with this and this worked for me:

```
MATCH (ur:Role)-[c:CAN]->(e:Entitlement {action: "see"})-[o:ON]->(s:Role {id:'msci'}) 
with collect(e) as rels where size(rels) > 1
with tail(rels) as tail
match(n:Entitlement {id: tail[0].id})
detach delete n
```

You'd need to run two queries one for each action but as long as it's only got the one extra relationship it should work.

Comment: No, does not work. The action was to uniquely identify the entitlement type. Without it, it considers both 'see' and 'execute' as the same and hence ends up deleting them.

Comment: this would work if there is only one extra relation right? So if I have another node p4 with duplicate entitlements to m1, it would only delete one of the duplicates from either p1 or p4. Added the example for this as well. Aplogies for the late edits.

Comment: Correct, it only works if there's one extra and of course you'd have to run it twice to get it to work for each type of entitlement. You might look into correcting the error that's causing the extra nodes in the first place, which might save you more work here in the end.

Comment: Yes, was trying that as well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796752/move-relationship-between-nodes-and-avoid-duplicates