# Move relationship between nodes and avoid duplicates

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a sample graph which looks like this:
[image: Graph]

So the nodes p1,p2 and p3 have see and execute entitlements on m1 and j1.
I need to move all entitlements from j1 to m1.

So the final graph should look like this:

I tried it with the query:

```
MATCH (ur:Role)-[c:CAN]->(e:Entitlement)-[o:ON]->(s:Role { id:'j1'})
OPTIONAL MATCH  (t:Role {id:'m1'})
CREATE (e)-[o2:ON]->(t)
set o2=o
delete o
```

This works, but it also creates duplicate entitlements in the graph which I need to avoid.
[image: Post Query]

What I need is this. To avoid duplicates which are already present on m1.

[image: Good graph]

I also tried a `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` but it does not work as well.

Also, I have a restriction to not use `APOC` procedures.

Comment: What do you mean by MERGE does not work as well? Are you talking about performance? Also, why can't you use APOC? Just curious.

Comment: Correct, using merge instead of create in the query does not work as well. For Apoc, I think they are not enabled

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work as well"? Also, if the existing `See` entitlement for `m1` happens to have different properties than the `See` entitlement for `j1` -- do you want to completely replace all the existing properties?

Comment: @cybersam The properties are same for the entitlements. I want to avoid the duplicate entitlements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things, looking at your graphs:

- The first graph has 8 Entitlements, the desired end result has 6. So
  there is no "duplication". You just keep the nodes you already had
  :)
- What your query is doing, is exactly what you say it should do , namely moving entitlements from one node to the other.

What is missing in my opinion, is the de-duplication step, which you could do like this (not tested)

```
// get all the patterns where you have > 1 entitlement of the same "type" (see or execute)
MATCH (n:Role)-->(e:Entitlement)-->(m:Role)
WITH n,m,e.type AS EntitlementType,
     COLLECT(e) AS Entitlements    
WHERE size(Entitlements) > 1

// delete all entitlements, except the first one
FOREACH (e IN tail(Entitlements) |
     DETACH DELETE e
)
```

Comment: Correct. the de-duplication was missing. For now this would work. I was thinking if there was a way to avoid the duplicates while copying itself.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid deleting the duplicates explicitly. At least not withing the boundaries that you set, like not using apoc, which has possibilities to merge nodes. If my answer is correct, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

This query creates only non-duplicate `Entitlement` nodes:

```
MATCH (m1:Role), (x:Role)-[:CAN]->(e:Entitlement)-[o:ON]->(j1:Role)
WHERE m1.id = 'm1' AND j1.id = 'j1'
CALL apoc.do.when(
  NOT EXISTS((x)-[:CAN]->({type: e.type})-[:ON]->(m1)),
  'CREATE (e)-[o2:ON]->(m1) SET o2 = o',
  '',
  {e: e, m1: m1, o: o}) YIELD value
DELETE o
```

The APOC function [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/cypher-execution/conditionals/#conditionals-when) is used to optionally perform the `CREATE` and `SET` clauses.

[UPDATE]

If you cannot use APOC, you can use a [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/clauses/foreach/) hack:

```
MATCH (m1:Role), (x:Role)-[:CAN]->(e:Entitlement)-[o:ON]->(j1:Role)
WHERE m1.id = 'm1' AND j1.id = 'j1'
FOREACH(x IN
  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS((x)-[:CAN]->({type: e.type})-[:ON]->(m1)) THEN [1] END |
  CREATE (e)-[o2:ON]->(m1)
  SET o2 = o
)
DELETE o
```

Comment: How can you have conditions without the apoc.do.when?

Comment: This does not work, it still creates the duplicates.